# How to generate the correct sitemap namespace using JAXB and Spring @ResponseBody in controller?

Tags: spring, controller, jaxb, sitemap

Everything is working fine with the exception that I cannot create the namespace correctly. Any help is much appreciated!

My controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sitemap")
public class SitemapController
{
    public @ResponseBody XMLURLSet getSitemap(){
       XMLURLSet urlSet = new XMLURLSet();
       //populate urlList
       urlSet.setUrl(urlList);
       return urlSet;
    }
}
```

My urlset:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "url")
public class XMLURL {
   String loc;
   @XmlElement(name = "loc")
   public String getLoc(){
      return loc;
   }
   public void setLoc(String loc){
   this.loc = loc;
}
```

}

My url element:

```
   @XmlRootElement(name = "urlset", namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")
    public class XMLURLSet{
       List<XMLURL> url;
       public List<XMLURL> getUrl(){
          return url;
       }
       public void setUrl(List<XMLURL> url){
       this.url = url;
    }

}
```

What I expected to be generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>
</url>
```

What got generated:

```
<ns2:urlset xmlns:ns2="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>
</url>
</ns2:urlset>
</urlset>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can leverage the `@XmlSchema` annotation to specify elementFormDefault is qualified.  This should help with your use case.

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: Where can I find the content of the file package-info?

Comment: `package-info` is actually a class so you will have a `package-info.java` in the same package as your domain classes with content similar to what is given in my answer.

Comment: it works. on the same thread, how would you add the encoding of the XML to generate <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>. I have seen how to do it manipulating the Marshler, though, my code does not allow me to do that

Comment: @Pomario - By default JAXB will generate a head (the following may help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-java-io-files-streams-readers.html).  In your use case JAXB may be marshalling into a stream started by spring so you may need to configure something at that level.